# How can I query all rows that are currently before data specified in one column in table?

Tags: sql-server

I need to get all rows tha are valid, ValidDate is column that shows how long these database items are valid. I need to get only valid items from the database. How can I do that? I use SQL Server.

Comment: can you edit your question to show what the DB looks like and what you are tying to do?  More info please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `ValidDate` means valid until:

```
SELECT Cols
FROM MyTable
WHERE getdate() <= ValidDate
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this perhaps?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ValidDate => GETDATE()
```

Comment: Ok, my bad, didn't have access to SQL Server db at the time of writing my answer...